# How to use callback function in SharePoint Client Object Model?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

SharePoint 2013 : I need to call my method only when execution of my method using Client Object Model REST API is completed. See below example:

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
                function getListData() {
                    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    web = context.get_web();
                    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('myList');
                    var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    myquery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                "</IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>");
                   myItems = list.getItems(myquery);
                    context.load(myItems);
                    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { getListDataSuccess(); }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.getListDataFailed));
                }
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    getListData();
                    // I need to call my method here.
                    //Once getListDataSuccess method is completed then only I need to call some other function based on the result of getListDataSuccess method.
                });
            </script>
```

I can call my method inside getListDataSuccess  but that is not the case here. There are several other methods lined up which are using Client Object Model REST API just one after other. So that only callback option is left out.
Similar kind of callback functionality is available in JQuery and SPServices. But not sure how it works with SharePoint Client Object Model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since JSOM is *asynchronous*, two approaches are commonly used to control the sequential execution of asynchronous calls in SharePoint:

- Callbacks
- Deferred

### Callback approach

With callback approach you declare your function like this

```
function getListData(listTitle,success,error)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

    context.load(items);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          success(items);           
        },
        error
    );
}
```

Usage

```
getListData('Documents',
         function(items){
            console.log('Items count: ' + items.get_count());
         },
         function(sender,args){
            console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
});
```

### Deferred approach

Deferred approach is based on a Promises pattern, please refer [this article](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/03/04/using-promises-with-the-javascript-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) for a details about the usage of Promises with CSOM

> A deferred - is a pattern that returns an object immediately from an
>   asynchronous call

```
function getListData(listTitle,success,error)
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
      var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var web = context.get_web();
      var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
      var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

      context.load(items);
      context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
           dfd.resolve(items);           
        },
        function (sender, args) {
           dfd.reject(args);
        }
      );
    });
    return dfd.promise();   
}
```

Usage

```
getListData('Documents').then(function(items){
    console.log('Items count: ' + items.get_count());
});
```